# Opencv FeatureMatching + Homography

Tags: python, opencv3.0, android, homography, opencv

I'm working on object detection demo using OpenCV. I've followed OpenCV's original doc "featurematching 2d + Homography" using Python. I've changed 'SIFT' to 'ORB'within code.

When I get Homography coordinates then I've applied getPerspectiveTransform & warpPerspective to crop and rotate the image according to its source image.

below is my perspective python code -

```
size = img1.shape

perspectiveM = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(np.float32(dst),pts)

img_dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img2,perspectiveM,size)

plt.imshow(img3, 'gray'),plt.show()
```

It is working perfect but in some cases, It couldn't align to its exact source. Below is source Image and scene Image -

[source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjfBk.jpg)

Here is my actual 'Homography' output -

[Homography output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8cZv.jpg)

I do this on the mobile platform (android) for testing I've used python. I didn't understand how can I fix this. I google it, I found that I've to consider camera calibration, distortion or decompose Homography.

I read about it and somehow understand above concept. But, I didn't understand How to implement them/which to get the accurate result.

my python code using orb -

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 6

img1 = cv2.imread('homo images/source.jpg',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('homo images/scene.jpg',0)          # trainImage

# Initiate ORB detector
sift = cv2.ORB_create()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with ORB
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# FLANN parameters
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params= dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_LSH,
                   table_number = 6, # 12
                   key_size = 12,     # 20
                   multi_probe_level = 1) #2

search_params = dict(checks=100)   # or pass empty dictionary

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
good = []

# Need to draw only good matches, so create a mask
#matchesMask = [[0,0] for i in xrange(len(matches))]

# ratio test as per Lowe's paper
for m_n in matches:
    if len(m_n) != 2:
        continue
    (m,n) = m_n
    if m.distance < 0.9*n.distance:
        #matchesMask[i]=[1,0]
        good.append(m)

if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

    h,w = img1.shape
    pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)

    img2 = cv2.polylines(img2,[np.int32(dst)],True,255,3, cv2.LINE_AA)

else:
    print "Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT)
    matchesMask = None

draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0),
                   singlePointColor = None,
                   matchesMask = matchesMask,
                   flags = 0)

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,**draw_params)

size = img1.shape

perspectiveM = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(np.float32(dst),pts)

img_dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img2,perspectiveM,size)

plt.imshow(img3, 'gray'),plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you post examples of good(expected) / bad outputs ?